# Alternativa de fetchAll

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

tengo este código donde mando a llamar a una fila con datos de una prenda (nombre,cantidad,color,etc), y quiero saber si hay una manera de que no use un foreach por que estoy usando un FetchAll, anteriormente usaba PDO para traer el valor de la columna en la fila de manera que antes era algo asi: `echo $variable[0][1];`

Estoy abierto a sugerencias y comentarios de este pequeño problema que tengo, gracias.

```
<?php 
include 'bd/conexion.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Productos INNER JOIN Detalle_Producto WHERE idProducto = '" . $_GET['btnmodificar'] . "'";



if (isset($_GET['btnmodificar'])) {
    echo '<script>console.log("Funcionando");</script>';
    $sentencia = $PDO->prepare($sql);
    $sentencia->execute();
    $resultado = $sentencia->fetchAll();
    // var_dump($resultado);

} 
else{
    echo '<script>alert("Ha ocurrido un error");</script>';
}


?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <?php foreach ($resultado as $item) : ?>
        <h2>
            <?php echo $item['Nombre_Producto']; ?>
        </h2>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: En teoría no hay problema, pero me incomoda estar usando un foreach por el fetchAll, me es un tanto innecesario estando colocando cada vez que quiera añadir un dato nuevo.

Comment: Bueno la verdad sí, es menos expresivo, pero tambien son menos lineas de código a comparación de como lo hacia antes, igualmente gracias por el comentario amigo

Comment: En lugar de `->fetchAll()` usa `->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` y con eso eliminas la necesidad del `[0]`.

Comment: gracias, me funcionó

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que `fetchAll()` te devuelve un array y dentro de ese array varios sub-arrays por cada fila, de modo que al hacer esto:

```
$resultado = $sentencia->fetchAll();
```

Todas las filas estarán en el índice `0` de `$resultado`.

PDO tiene varias alternativas, según la necesitad que tengas.

### Se espera una sola fila

En ese caso, optimiza la consulta SQL agregando al final `LIMIT 1` y accede a los datos mediante el método `fetch`:

```
#Cambiaremos a consultas preparadas (ver al final)
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Productos INNER JOIN Detalle_Producto WHERE idProducto = :idProducto LIMIT 1";
$resultado = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Aquí `$resultado` será **la fila única que esperas** y luego podrás acceder a cada columna con algo como `$resultado["laColumna"]` simplemente.

### Se espera una sola fila/columna

Entonces puedes usar [`fetchColumn()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php):

```
$sql = "SELECT columnaUnica FROM Productos INNER JOIN Detalle_Producto WHERE idProducto = :idProducto LIMIT 1";
$resultado = $sentencia->fetchColumn();
```

Aquí `$resultado` será **el valor en sí** de la columna única que esperas de una fila única**.

### Se esperan varias filas

Entonces el bucle es obligatorio de cualquier modo. En este caso hay que decidir varias cosas:

a. Si esperas muchas filas/columnas evita el uso de `fetchAll()`, porque este método vuelca de golpe el conjunto de resultados. Si son muchas filas y la capacidad de memoria es excedida el script bloqueará/causará un crash. En ese caso es mejor usar `fetch`

b. Si decides usar `fetch`, y los datos se necesitan *in situ*, entonces abre un bucle que recorra el puntero de los resultados y velos mostrando/concatenando en una variable (por ejemplo cuando construyes una tabla o lista usando la información).

c. Si decides usar `fetch` y los datos necesitan ser devueltos a otra parte, entonces llena un array desde el bucle donde lees con `fetch` y devuelve ese array.

```
#El LIMIT 1 desaparece porque se esperan varias filas
$sql = "SELECT columnaUnica FROM Productos INNER JOIN Detalle_Producto WHERE idProducto = :idProducto";

while ($row = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  #Aquí imprimes o guardas cada fila según necesidad explicadas en (b) y (c)
  # (b) echo $row["laColumna"] ....  o concatenar a una variable
  # (c) $elArrayADevolver[]=$row;
}
```

**NOTA IMPORTANTE**, pasa siempre a `fetch` y a `fetchAll` de forma explícita el método en que debe organizar los datos. En este caso estamos pasando siempre: `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`, si no lo haces usará el método por defecto, que es `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` el cual devuelve un array indexado tanto por nombre de columna, como numéricamente con índice de base 0 tal como fue devuelto en el conjunto de resultados. Eso puede ser trágico para la memoria cuando manejas muchos datos.

---

### Sobre la seguridad de tu código

Tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Estás usando mal el método `prepare`, porque tu instrucción SQL no es preparada, pasas el dato directamente. Debes poder un marcador y pasar el dato con `bindParam` ([ver aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php) para más detalles).

```
$idProducto=!empty($_GET['btnmodificar']) ? $_GET['btnmodificar'] : NULL;
if ($idProducto) {
    echo '<script>console.log("Funcionando");</script>';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Productos INNER JOIN Detalle_Producto WHERE idProducto = :idProducto";
    $sentencia = $PDO->prepare($sql);
    $sentencia->bindParam(':idProducto', $idProducto, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sentencia->execute();
    #Usar el fetch que más te convenga

}
```